# How to read lines to dictionary with linQ

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Ok i got the below code but it is not working

I want lines to be key and values to be 0

c# 4.5

```
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> dicFailedProxies = 
    new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();

   dicFailedProxies = File.ReadAllLines("failed_proxies.txt")
   .Select(line => line).Distinct()
   .ToDictionary(values => values, 0);
```

[image]

Comment: -1 for "it is not working" - elaborate.

Comment: image added for those who wonders the error

Comment: You're calling `ToDictionary` incorrectly. See the documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Please enter the *text* of the error, not a screenshot of it's text.

Comment: Why make it a dictionary if every value is 0?

Comment: @valverij For later manipulation of the value, I'm assuming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you need to provide a lambda expression for the second argument of `ToDictionary`. `ToDictionary` also returns a `Dictionary<T, U>` so you won't be able to assign it to an instance of `ConcurrentDictionary<T, U>`.

This should do the trick:

```
var dicFailedProxies = 
    File.ReadLines("failed_proxies.txt")
        .Distinct()
        .ToDictionary(line => line, line => 0);
```

Of course, if you want to keep it as a  `ConcurrentDictionary<T, U>` you can do this:

```
var dicFailedProxies = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>(
    File.ReadLines("failed_proxies.txt")
        .Distinct()
        .ToDictionary(line => line, line => 0));
```

Comment: there's really no need for the `Select` transformation, no?

Comment: @Tejas Correct; it accomplishes nothing.

Comment: heh yeah, it was more of a rhetorical question. I would just edit that out @p.s.w.g

Comment: @Tejas Good point. Thanks

Comment: yes i got it know that it is impossible to assign concurrentdictionary thanks

Comment: Also should really use `ReadLines`, not `ReadAllLines`.  It will do exactly the same thing but with a smaller memory footprint as you'll be streaming the data.